# Limit of a Function as x goes to Infinity: Proof Verification Using the Definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, proof-verification

I have written out a proof for this question, although it feels wrong.

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+5x+5}\right)$

Take any Ɛ>0, I started by finding $|\frac{x^2}{x^2+5x+5}-1|$, which gives me $\frac{5|x+1|}{|x^2+5x+5|}$.

From here is where I am confused.

I restricted $d\leq2$, so $|x+1|\leq2$ and $-3\leq x\leq1$.

I factored $x^2+5x+5$ to get $(x+\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2})(x+\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2})$, and then using the above inequality for x I found that $|\frac{1}{(x+\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2})}|\leq\frac{2}{-1+\sqrt{5}}$ and $|\frac{1}{(x+\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2})}|\leq\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}$.

Then: $\frac{5|x+1|}{|x^2+5x+5|}\leq 5|x+1|(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}})(\frac{2}{-1+\sqrt{5}})=\frac{5}{2}|x+1|$.

So $\frac{5}{2}|x+1|\leqƐ$ iff $|x+1|\leq\frac{2Ɛ}{5}$.

Now choose d=max{2, $\frac{2Ɛ}{5}$}, given Ɛ>0.

This proof feels wrong, although I am confused as to how to better prove limits where x goes to infinity, as the text I am using as reference only shows a very simple example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $d$ meant to be. It appears out of nowhere.

Comment: I think they meant $\delta$.

Comment: @copper.hat In my reference text, the definition for the limit of a function as x approaches infinity is "... for any Ɛ>0, there exists a real number d>0 such that |f(x)-L|<Ɛ for all x satisfying x>d". From what I've seen online I believe other texts replace d with delta?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really restrict the $x$, it is $x\rightarrow\infty$, not $0<|x-c|<\delta$, there cannot be any restriction.

To show the convergence, for any $\epsilon>0$ and $x\geq(10/\epsilon)+1$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+5x+5}-1\right|&=\dfrac{5|x+1|}{|x^{2}+5x+5|}\\
&=\dfrac{5(x+1)}{x^{2}+5x+5}\\
&\leq\dfrac{5(x+x)}{x^{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{10}{x}\\
&<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Note that for $x\geq 1$, $x^{2}+5x+5>0$.

Comment: Interesting. So I've essentially made this question way more complicated than it needs to be. This makes perfect sense - thank you!

Comment: You don't really need to factorize the quadratic. You are basically looking at the highest term, which is $x^{2}$, for the rest of the lower terms, try to loose them.

Answer (score 1):

Option:

$x>0:$

$f(x):=\dfrac{5(x+1)}{x^2+5x+5} <$

$\dfrac{5(x+1)}{(x+1)^2} = \dfrac{5}{x+1}<\dfrac{5}{x}$.

$\epsilon >0$ given.

Choose $M = 5/\epsilon$.

For $x > M:$

$f(x)< \dfrac{5}{x} <5/M =\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $L$ such that
for $x>L$ then $|5{x+1 \over x^2+5x+5} | < \epsilon$.

First, as a reality check I divide above and below by the largest power of $x$ to get
$|5{{1 \over x} +{1 \over x^2}\over 1+{5 \over x} + {5 \over x^2}} | $ and it is
hopefully intuitively clear that this converges to zero, so we can find such an $L$.

Now we get to the tricks stage. Note that for $x>0$ (which is fair game here)
we have $x^2+5x+5 \ge x^2+2x+1 = (x+1)^2 > 0$, so
$|5{x+1 \over x^2+5x+5}| \le | 5 {x+1 \over (x+1)^2}| = 5{1 \over |x+1|}$.

Now we need to pick $L$ such that if $x>L$ then the right hand quantity above is
less than $\epsilon$. It is not too hard to see that if $L >{5 \over \epsilon}-1$
then we will get the desired result. No point in being stingy, so might as well
write $L > {5 \over \epsilon}$.

Note that there really is no real recipe for picking the estimate above, since we
have $x+1$ as a numerator I looked at $(x+1)^2$ first and this worked.